# Janela acumulada em R

Tags: r

Preciso fazer um ranking de dias baseados numa janela cumulativa de todos os dias anteriores a ele. No caso, preciso começar com uma janela de 252 dias, ordenar as observações, fazer um ranking de 20 percentis igualmente distribuídos. Daí pegar a observação do dia 253, comparar com esse rank, se tiver dentro dos valores do rank, classificar de acordo com ele, se for menor que o mínimo, classificar como 0 e se for maior que o máximo, classificar como 21. 
Feito isso, preciso correr essa função por toda a base, aumentando a janela do rank, começando por 252 dias, indo pra 253, e assim por diante.

Eu possuo o seguinte código, que faz exatamente o que falei no começo, mas com a janela fixa de 252 dias.

```
    qtl.rank2<-function(x,obs.1=1,obs.t=252,qtl.intl=20)
{
  #x: list;
  #obs.1: calibragem, 1a obs;
  #obs.t: calibragem, última obs;
  #qtl.intl: quantidade de intervalos.

  x.length<-length(x) #tamanho da lista
  i<-t #contador dos quantis
  j<-1 #contador
  qtl.width<-100/qtl.intl #tamanho do intervalo
  pi<-0 #inicializa variável que armazena o quantil
  pi.vec<-matrix(0,nrow=qtl.intl,ncol=1) #matriz para armazenar os percentis

  calibration.list<-list(0,obs.t)

  matriz.resultados<-matrix(0,nrow=(x.length-obs.t),2)

  for(i in obs.1:(x.length-obs.t))
  {
    calibration.list <- x[i:(i+obs.t-1)]  
    pctl<-quantile(calibration.list,1:qtl.intl*qtl.width/100)
    pi.vec<-as.matrix(pctl)
    rownames(pi.vec)<-rownames(as.matrix(pctl))
    colnames(pi.vec)<-"Percentis"

    new.pi.vec<-matrix(c(pi.vec,0),nrow=qtl.intl+1,ncol=1)

    new.pi.vec[qtl.intl+1,]<-x[i+obs.t]

    o<-order(new.pi.vec, decreasing=FALSE)
    new.pi.vec<-as.matrix(new.pi.vec[o,])

    res<-c(x[i+obs.t],which(new.pi.vec[,1]==x[i+obs.t],arr.ind=TRUE))
    num_aval<-res[1]
    qtl.order<-res[2]

    if(qtl.order==1)
    {
      print(calibration.list)
      if(num_aval<min(calibration.list))
      {
        qtl.order<-0
      }

    res<-c(num_aval,qtl.order)

    }

    matriz.resultados[i,1]<-res[1]
    matriz.resultados[i,2]<-res[2]

    if(i<x.length-(obs.t+1)){print(matriz.resultados[i+1,])}

    print(c(i,res))

  }
 return(matriz.resultados)
}
```

Como eu ajusto esse código pra que ele possa ir acumulando os dias da janela pra fazer o ranking?

Obrigada!